# See if motherboard has HDMI with CEC

Tags: hdmi

is it possible to see if the motherboard has CEC support through HDMI? Running Ubuntu 14.04 Server

I have a Asrock Q1900DC-ITX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that by installing cec-utils

```
sudo apt-get install cec-utils libcec-dev
```

and start

```
cec-client -l
```

This will list all CEC devices on your system.